# How to find row-echelon matrix form (not reduced) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I am working on a project for my Linear Algebra class. I am stuck with a small problem. I could not find any method for finding the row-echelon matrix form (not reduced) in Python (not MATLAB).
Could someone help me out?
Thank you.

(I use python3.x)

Answer (score 3):

Bill M's answer is correct. When you find the LU decomposition the U matrix is a  correct way of writing M in REF (note that REF is not unique so there are multiple possible ways to write it). To see why, remember that the LU decomposition finds P,L,U such that PLU = M. When L is full rank we can write this as U = (PL)<sup>-1</sup>M. So (PL)<sup>-1</sup> defines the row operations that you have to preform on M to change it into U.

Comment: because scipy lu doesn't always return in row echelon form.  See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891334/

Answer (score 2):

I think [scipy.linalg's "lu"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html) can do that:

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import lu
>>> import numpy as np
>>> M = np.array([[0,3,-6,6,4,-5], [3,-7,8,-5,8,9], [3,-9,12,-9,6,15]])
>>> p,l,u = lu(M)
>>> u
array([[ 3.        , -7.        ,  8.        , -5.        ,  8.        ,  9.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  3.        , -6.        ,  6.        ,  4.        , -5.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.66666667, 2.66666667]])
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, for responding me but this way does not help me out. For this reason, when you find 'u' which indicates M = L * U, it only finds 2 different matrixes which are like the components of M. However, if we want to get ref version of M, it is required to do some row operations on M. So 'L*U' is just one way to write the matrix, REF requires to modify the M. They are different.